# values of particular coloumb not displaying inspite of passing entire table to the view .

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hey guys below is what my data base looks like:

[image: database]

Now in my blade template if i do the following:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
                   <li>
                       Category created at {{ $category->id }} 
                   </li> 
 @endforeach
```

I get an output of

```
Category created at 1
```

same with `created_at` and `updated_at`, I.E. i get the values, but not for name , for `name` , i get the following:

```
Category created at
```

Which means the name is not being displayed, i don't know why, but its not being displayed , can somebody tell me why , in my controller i am passing the entire table to the `view`, so why am i not being able to fetch the value of `name` ?

can anybody explain this phenomenon ?

Comment: plz add code where you fetch data from database and where you show name